# snowflake version of a teradata case to remove minus value

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

what would be the Snowflake counterpart of following Teradata SQL?

```
select   CAST( CAST((   2*-1 )AS FORMAT '9.99') AS CHAR(4))
```

will give
"2.00"

however in Snowflake,

```
select CAST(to_char((   2*-1), 'FM0.00' ) AS CHAR(5));
```

gives:
"-2.00"

(example was simplified)

How to get rid of the - symbol?

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably using ABS() is a good workaround:

```
select CAST(to_char((   abs(2*-1)), 'FM0.00' ) AS CHAR(5));
```

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/abs.html